# What's wrong with this code? Can't search by decimal and date

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, nhibernate

I'm using jQuery table which is connected to a table in database in my webpage using ASP.NET MVC 4.5.

I have written my controller and I'm trying to search for data using the search box and so far I can search for something like Name, ID, phone as its all defined as strings in my class but when it comes to searching by date or salary (decimals) it won't work. any idea? I am totally new to C# - here is some of my controller below:

```
public ActionResult BankPaymentListing(string id)//
{
    //using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    //{
    //    if (session.IsNotNull())
    //    {
    //        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    //        {
    //            try
    //            {
    //                var fieldName = new[] {"RCNO"}.ToList();

    //                ViewBag.message = DataRetrieveHelper.GetNextRunningNumReset(session, "CLPAYM", fieldName, DateTime.Now, true, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0 ,0 ,1));
    //                transaction.Commit();
    //            }
    //            catch (Exception ex)
    //            {
    //                ex.WriteExToLog();
    //                transaction.Rollback();
    //            }
    //        }

    //    }
    //}

    ViewBag.ID = id;
    return View();     
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BankPaymentListingAction(FormCollection fm, McJqDataTableParameter param)
{
    var rtObj = new McJqDatatableServerReturnObject
    {
        sEcho = param.sEcho,
        iTotalRecords = 97,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = 3,
        aaData = new List<string[]>()
    };
    try
    {
        if (fm != null)
        {
            var allFiledList = new List<string>();
            if (fm["sColumns"].IsNotNull())
            {
                var filterFields = fm["sColumns"].Split(',');
                allFiledList.AddRange(filterFields.Where(t => t.IsNotNullNotTrimEmpty()));
            }
            var ascArray = new ArrayList();
            var descArray = new ArrayList();
            for (var c = 0; c < param.iColumns; c++)
            {
                if (fm["sSortDir_" + c] == null) continue;
                if (fm["sSortDir_" + c].ToUpper().CompareEq("ASC"))
                {
                    ascArray.Add(allFiledList[Convert.ToInt32(fm["iSortCol_0"])]);
                }
                else if (fm["sSortDir_" + c].ToUpper().CompareEq("DESC"))
                {
                    descArray.Add(allFiledList[Convert.ToInt32(fm["iSortCol_0"])]);
                }
            }
            var ascSort = string.Join(",", ascArray.ToArray());
            var descSort = string.Join(",", descArray.ToArray());
            ascArray.Clear();
            descArray.Clear();
            if (ascSort.IsNullOrTrimEmpty() && descSort.IsNullOrTrimEmpty())
            {
                ascSort = allFiledList[0];
            }

            using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                if (session.IsNotNull())      
                {         
                    var criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Pybkdtl))
                        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("PybkhdrId", new Guid(fm["ID"])));

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchValue"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchType"]))
                    {
                        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like(fm["SearchType"], "%" + fm["SearchValue"] + "%")); 
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchValue"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchType"]))
                    {
                        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like(fm["SearchType"], "%" + fm["Icno"] + "%"));
                    }


                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchValue"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchType"]))
                    {
                        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like(fm["SearchType"], "%" + fm["MobileNo"] + "%"));
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchValue"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchType"]))
                    {
                        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like(fm["SearchType"], "%" + fm["ReferenceNo"] + "%"));

                        //decimal SearchValue = decimal.Parse(fm["SearchValue"]); 
                    }

                    decimal Amount;
                    if (decimal.TryParse(fm["searchValue"], out Amount))
                    {
                        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq(fm["searchValue"], "Amount"));
                    }

                    DateTime date;
                    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(fm["SearchValue"], "dd/MM/YYYY", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                    {
                        criteria.Add(Expression.Ge(fm["TransactionDate"]
                        criteria.Add(Expression.Le(fm["TransactionDate"],
                    }
```

Comment: You should post only the *relevant* parts of your code, otherwise you make it difficult for people to help. That `catch{}` also guarantees any errors will go unnoticed. Did you try debugging the code? Are you sure your code doesn't fail before even trying to make a query? Eg if you pass some random string, `TryParse` will return false but your code will never warn you.

Comment: i have taken out some unnecessary code and yes it worked but it wouldnt work if i want to search by decimal or date ...i guess there is something wrong with the add criteria but i cant tell which one is it

Comment: I think you *added* code, which made things worse. There are far too many points where things can go wrong and mixing up dates, strings, and FormCollection is guaranteed to cause problems. Create a **minimal** example instead - just a console application, an NHibernate query and a single criteria, where you pass a *DateTime* value, not a string from FormCollection. Once you get this to work, you can start looking at how to add criteria dynamically

Comment: PS - I just saw a line ` criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq(fm["searchValue"], "Amount")); ` . This means compare the `Amount` field to the **string** stored in the dictionary fm, not the decimal value. Any localization differences will make your query fail with an error - which is hidden by that `catch{}` statement

Comment: well, i dont even know how to do a console application, am totally new to mvc and c# but so far the criteria for all of the strings are working such as, mobile no ref no,customer name but not the amount (decimal) and datetime, is the tryparce format correct ?i have no idea what to do.

Comment: i felt there is something wrong with that line Eq(fm["searchValue"], "Amount")); but how it suppose to be ?

Comment: Amount should not be a string, it should be the variable you declared before. The date part wouldn't even compile as you have it in the question. I get the feeling that all this is a bit too hard for your experience. NHibernate alone has a very steep learning curve. The whole code is a very bad example of mixing things that should be on separate layers in any application. It seems to be very far of a working and maintainable application.

Answer (score 0):

the parameters are incorrect: `Restrictions.Eq(fm["searchValue"], "Amount"))` should be `Restrictions.Eq("Amount", Amount))`

Beside that the code looks messy:

- posted only half the code. ends in the middle
- .NET naming conventions are not met
- excessive null checks with no error handling